# ocaml program doesnt display image when executed on cygwin terminal

Tags: cygwin, ocaml, graphviz, dot, automata

I have written a program that writes an automaton's diagram from a list of nodes and edges in a dot file and opens it via the unix module in `ocaml` using `imagemagick`. It worked fine and it has opened the generated image when compiled and executed on linux but on `cygwin`, it doesn't work for some reason. I already installed `graphviz` and `imagemagick` on `cygwin` but no luck. Here is the code of the program:

```
(*d'abord definissons le type automate*)

type automate = {
    etat_initial : int;
    ensemble_des_etats : int list;
    alphabets : char list;
    transitions :(int*char*int) list;
    etats_finaux : int list
};;

(*prenons une variable a1 du type automate qu'on a definit precedemment comme exemple*)

let a1={
    etat_initial=1;
    ensemble_des_etats=[1;2];
    alphabets=['a';'b'];
    transitions=[(1,'a',1);(1,'b',2);(2,'a',2);(2,'b',1)];
    etats_finaux=[2]
};;

(*pour tester si un automate est complet ou non on a besoin de trois fonctions*)
(*la premiere donne l'image d'un couple (etat,caractere) par une transition*)

let rec image e a t= 
match t with 
[]->[]
|x::l-> let (i,j,k)=x in if (i=e && j=a) then k::(image e a l) 
else image e a l ;;

(*la deuxieme donne une liste qui contient tout les couples d'un etat (etat,caractere)
 qui n'ont pas d'image donc si image e la lt=[] cela veut dire que l'automate est n'est pas complet dans cet etat*)

let rec nodef e la lt=
match la with
| [] -> []
| a::la'-> if image e a lt = [] then (e,a)::nodef e la' lt else nodef e la' lt;;

(*la troisieme applique nodef sur tout les element d'une liste*)

let rec est_complet le la lt =
match le with
| [] -> []
| e::le'-> nodef e la lt :: est_complet le' la lt;;

  (*ici c'est l'application directe de toutes les fonctions precedentes sur un automate*)

let complet auto=
if est_complet auto.ensemble_des_etats auto.alphabets auto.transitions = []
then true else false ;;

(*la partie qui teste est ce qu'un automate est complet termine ici*)
(*on s'interesse maintenant a faire une fonction qui teste si un automate est deterministe*)
(*d'abord on realie la fonction membre qui retourne true si un element donné en parametre est membre d'une liste false sinon*)

let rec membre a l =
    match l with
    | [] -> false
    | x::rl -> x=a || membre a rl;;

(*ensuite on definie deux fonctions dans une*) 

let est_det a=

(*la premiere pour voir si une liste contient des doublons*)

let rec appartient l = match l with 
[] -> false
| x::r -> (membre x r) || (appartient r);

in

(*la deuxieme pour rendre une liste de paires a partir d'une qui contenait des triplets*)

let rec mettre_en_couple l =
match l with
|[]->[]
|(a,b,c)::l1->(a,b)::mettre_en_couple l1;

in

(*et enfin on applique la premiere fonction sur la liste rendu par la deuxieme*)

let l = mettre_en_couple a
in
appartient l;;

let deterministe auto=
if est_det auto.transitions=false then true else false;;

(*ici c'est l'application directe de toutes les fonctions precedentes sur un automate*)

(*pour representer un automate graphiquement en utilisant graphviz on necessite 4 fonctions*)

(*la premiere pour ecrire dans un fichier qui sera passé par la sortie standard stdout vers la fonction dessiner_automate,le fichier fmt
 contiendra la description suivant la condition appliqué a une transition de l'automate du graph en langage dot*)
let fmt_transition auto fmt (inedge,by,outedge)=
    if membre outedge auto.etats_finaux=true then
 Format.fprintf fmt "@[node [shape = doublecircle]%d;@]" outedge;
 if inedge=auto.etat_initial then
 Format.fprintf fmt "@[node [shape = point]start;node [shape = circle];start -> %d ;@]"inedge ;
 Format.fprintf fmt "@[%d -> %d [label=\"%c\"];@]" inedge outedge by;;
(*la deuxieme fonction levera la premiere sur toute les transitions de l'automate *)
let fmt_transitions fmt auto=
 Format.fprintf fmt "@[<v 2>digraph output {@,%a@,@]}@,@."
  (Format.pp_print_list (fmt_transition auto)) auto.transitions
;;
(*la troisieme va lancer la commande d'affichage de l'image genere par le fichier dot passe en parametre dans 
un environement linux depuis ocaml *)
let dessiner_automate auto =
  let cmd = "dot -Tpng | display -" in
  let (sout, sin, serr) as channels =
    Unix.open_process_full cmd (Unix.environment ()) in
  let fmt = Format.formatter_of_out_channel sin in
  Format.fprintf fmt "%a@." fmt_transitions auto;
  channels 

let cleanup channels =
  (* missing: flush channels, empty buffers *)
  Unix.close_process_full channels;;

  dessiner_automate a1 ;;

print_newline()
```

Comment: cygwin terminal is text mode not graphic. May be you should run in a Xterm under X ?

Comment: i installed the xinit and xorg packages tried executing the program nothing appears when i run display it says unable to open xserver

Comment: This is more a cygwin problem. Did you try to display an image with 'display' program ?

Comment: Read `https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html` to understand how to start the X Server and the Xterm

Comment: when i try to use display it says unable to start xserver

Comment: You are NOT running display from inside Xterm. You are likely using the Cygwin Terminal